# Signtool always says a parameter is missing

Tags: windows, pfx, signtool

I recently made a game in Unity3D and I am trying to sign the code with a certificate I bought from Comodo (saved in a pfx file).  I have done a ton of research on how to use it and have settled to running these commands:

```
doskey signtool="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Tools\bin\i386\signtool.exe"
signtool sign /f "C:\...[path to cert on desktop]...\cert.pfx" "C:\...[path to exe on desktop]...\Game.exe"
```

No matter what I do, or slight variations I try, or anything, I always get the same error:

```
SignTool Error: A required paramter is missing.
Usage: signtool <command> [options]
```

Even running "signtool sign /?" gives me this same error.  I don't understand why the program won't do or even tell me anything useful.  Some sources I've seen say I need to add a "/p passwordHere" after the /f option, but that gives the same error message as all others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must let `doskey` know that the macro `signtool` expects parameters, which are to be passed onto the real `signtool.exe`. This is done by appending `$*` at the end of the definition.

```
doskey signtool="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Tools\bin\i386\signtool.exe" $*
```

From the official [Doskey](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753867.aspx) docs (**highlight** mine):

> To run a macro, type the macro name at the command prompt, starting at the first position. **If the macro was defined with $* or any of the batch parameters $1 through $9**, use a space to separate the parameters.

Comment: I come from a unix background so I thought doskey worked the same as alias.  Thank you very much!